# byte[] to String not executing in query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code. What I am passing to the function GetInsert is the ID which then creates the INSERT Statement. Note that _Image1 is of type byte[]. Image1 is of type IMAGE in the database table. Note that the way I am doing below in terms of outputting a string I am kind of stuck with as it is part of a large piece of code.

```
    public string GetInsert(string ID)
    {

      System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

      stringBuilder .Append("INSERT INTO tblMain(ID,Image1) VALUES (");

      stringBuilder .Append((ID) + ", ");
      stringBuilder .Append(ByteToString(_Image1) + ")");

      return stringBuilder.ToString();

    }
```

Because the above code needs to be converted to a string, I converted _Image1 to a string as shown below. Please let me know if this is the correct approach.

```
    public string ByteToString(byte[] bytes)
    {

        if(bytes == null)
        {

            return "NULL";

        }
      else
      {
          return "'" + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) + "'";

      }

   }
```

Then elsewhere in the code I am doing the following to execute the insert statement:

```
    command.CommandText = obj1.GetInsert(sID);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The issue that I am running into is that when I do it as shown above the string that is converted is not in a way that is recognized when I the code tries to execute it in the ExecuteNonQuery. Please let me know if my approach is correct. Any suggest would be helpful

Comment: What kind of column is `Image1` in SQL?  VARCHAR(MAX), VARBINARY(MAX), IMAGE, something else?

Comment: I would suggest to use parameterized query and pass the byte array to type _image1

Comment: @DanField  It is of type Image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use command params insted of using StringBuilder and convert byte do string.

see [microsoft SqlCommand.Parameters docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your code should be like this:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblMain(ID,Image1) VALUES (@Id,@Image)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", sID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", _Image1);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you need to fix like this:

```
public string ByteToString(byte[] bytes)
{

    if(bytes == null)
    {

        return "NULL";

    }
  else
  {
      return "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
  }
```

}

BUT doing it this way you are asking for many troubles like sql injections. Just use parametrized queries instead.